# How to doPrivileged in kotlin coroutines?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, java-security-manager

In Java I can raise privileges by calling java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged().

How can I raise privileges in kotlin coroutines?

Example: When I call the program

```
import java.security.AccessControlContext
import java.security.AccessController
import java.security.PrivilegedAction
import java.security.ProtectionDomain
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

object Privileged {

  private fun checkDirect(expectAllowed: Boolean) {
    try {
      System.getProperty("allowed")
      if (expectAllowed) {
        println("expected: allowed")
      }
      else {
        println("UNEXPECTED: allowed")
      }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
      if (expectAllowed) {
        println("UNEXPECTED: forbidden")
      }
      else {
        println("expected: forbidden")
      }
    }
  }

  private suspend fun checkSuspend(expectAllowed: Boolean) {
    checkDirect(expectAllowed)
  }

  @JvmStatic
  fun main(vararg argv: String) {
    // drop privileges
    AccessController.doPrivileged(
      PrivilegedAction {
        // privileges are all dropped here

        // 1. direct functions:

        // this check will fail
        checkDirect(false)

        // raise privilege
        AccessController.doPrivileged(
          PrivilegedAction {
            // privileges are all raised here
            // so this check will succeed
            checkDirect(true)
          }
        )

        // 2. suspend functions:

        runBlocking {
          // this call will fail
          checkSuspend(false)

          // FIXME: How to call checkSuspend(true) with raised privileges?
        }
      },
      AccessControlContext(arrayOf(ProtectionDomain(null, null)))
    )
  }
}
```

with `java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=java.policy Privileged` where java.policy is

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I get

```
expected: forbidden
expected: allowed
expected: forbidden
```

What is the equivalent of AccessController.doPrivileged() for calling checkSuspend with raised privileges (see FIXME in the program code)?